# Simplest way to create Drag & Drop shopping cart - asp.net

Tags: asp.net, drag-and-drop, shopping-cart

What is the simplest way to create drag and drop shopping cart in ASP.NET. 
Is JQuery the only way?

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not the only way, but definitely one of the easiest ways... You can call an AJAX method in the drop event, so you can refresh the cart.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

Talking about the user experience, I'd not trust in this approach, even being as cool as it is, for something critical to your business like filling the shopping cart. It would be much easier for people to click on "Buy" than dragging something to somewhere. ;)